# Прозрачный status bar

Tags: android, ui

Можно ли изменить программно прозрачность статус бара?

Comment: ага, учитывая, что разные производители пытаются втиснуть свой мегалаунчер, задача стает интереснее. А на 4.4 он уже прозрачный (по крайней мере на лаунчере, который с пятым нексусом идет)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI Translucent system bars
Можно скачать примеры для последнего sdk, там есть в разделе интерфейса как это делать. Но это только для 19 API и выше

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно

```
  drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Эта функция только появилась в API 11, а я использую API 10 для совместимости с 2.3.3, получается, мне нужно использовать API 11, но выполнять эту функцию в зависимости от версии?

Comment: Мне кажется или этот код изменяет только фон статус бара? А мне нужно что бы весь статус бар, включая иконки были прозрачными.

Comment: иконки отдельно надо делать прозрачными

Comment: Это не статус бар, под статус баром я имел ввиду полоску с информацией о вайфае, батарее и тд, на самом верху экрана.

Comment: а куда это прописывать?